# Oracle capture variable and do if statement in SPROC

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle and I am trying to create a sproc.
Currently I have this:

```
procedure ListCatalogueEntries(P_CUR out sys_refcursor,
                               P_CATALOGUEID varchar2, P_UNIQUEPRODUCTS varchar2) is

BEGIN
    IF P_UNIQUEPRODUCTS = 'Y' THEN
        OPEN P_CUR FOR
        SELECT 
            corprd.sku        prodcode,
            corprd.rangecode  cor_rangecode,
            corprd.rangename  cor_rangename,
            corprd.prodcode   cor_colourcode,
            corprd.prodname   cor_colourname,
            corprd.sku        cor_partcode,
            corprd.skudesc    cor_partname,
            corprd.proddesc   cor_partdesc,
            corprd.prodspec   cor_partspec,
            e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
            e.rangename cus_rangename,
            e.productcode cus_colourcode,
            e.productname cus_colourname,
            e.buyercode cus_partcode,
            e.skudescription cus_partname,
            e.skudescription cus_partspec                              
        FROM
            ccvw_web_products corprd
        INNER JOIN 
            cc_ob_catalogueentries e
        ON 
            corprd.sku = e.sku
        WHERE 
            nvl(e.catalogueid,P_CATALOGUEID) = P_CATALOGUEID                   
        ORDER BY 
            e.sku;
    ELSE
        OPEN P_CUR FOR
        SELECT 
            corprd.sku        prodcode,
            corprd.rangecode  cor_rangecode,
            corprd.rangename  cor_rangename,
            corprd.prodcode   cor_colourcode,
            corprd.prodname   cor_colourname,
            corprd.sku        cor_partcode,
            corprd.skudesc    cor_partname,
            corprd.proddesc   cor_partdesc,
            corprd.prodspec   cor_partspec,
            e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
            e.rangename cus_rangename,
            e.productcode cus_colourcode,
            e.productname cus_colourname,
            e.buyercode cus_partcode,
            e.skudescription cus_partname,
            e.skudescription cus_partspec                              
        FROM
            ccvw_web_products corprd
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            cc_ob_catalogueentries e
        ON 
            corprd.rangecode = e.rangecode
        WHERE 
            nvl(e.catalogueid,P_CATALOGUEID) = P_CATALOGUEID                   
        ORDER BY 
            e.sku;
    END IF;          

END ListCatalogueEntries;
```

Which does compile.
What I am actually trying to achieve is this (This is in MSSQL):

```
DECLARE @CatalogueId NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Unique NVARCHAR(1)
SET @CatalogueId = 'Test'

SELECT @Unique = uniquecatalogue FROM cc_ob_catalogueheader WHERE Id = @CatalogueId

IF @Unique = 'N'
    SELECT 
        corprd.sku        prodcode,
        corprd.rangecode  cor_rangecode,
        corprd.rangename  cor_rangename,
        corprd.prodcode   cor_colourcode,
        corprd.prodname   cor_colourname,
        corprd.sku        cor_partcode,
        corprd.skudesc    cor_partname,
        corprd.proddesc   cor_partdesc,
        corprd.prodspec   cor_partspec,
        e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
        e.rangename cus_rangename,
        e.productcode cus_colourcode,
        e.productname cus_colourname,
        e.buyercode cus_partcode,
        e.skudescription cus_partname,
        e.skudescription cus_partspec                              
    FROM
        ccvw_web_products corprd
    INNER JOIN 
        cc_ob_catalogueentries e
    ON 
        corprd.sku = e.sku
    WHERE 
        nvl(e.catalogueid,P_CATALOGUEID) = P_CATALOGUEID                   
    ORDER BY 
        e.sku;
ELSE
    SELECT 
        corprd.sku        prodcode,
        corprd.rangecode  cor_rangecode,
        corprd.rangename  cor_rangename,
        corprd.prodcode   cor_colourcode,
        corprd.prodname   cor_colourname,
        corprd.sku        cor_partcode,
        corprd.skudesc    cor_partname,
        corprd.proddesc   cor_partdesc,
        corprd.prodspec   cor_partspec,
        e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
        e.rangename cus_rangename,
        e.productcode cus_colourcode,
        e.productname cus_colourname,
        e.buyercode cus_partcode,
        e.skudescription cus_partname,
        e.skudescription cus_partspec                              
    FROM
        ccvw_web_products corprd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        cc_ob_catalogueentries e
    ON 
        corprd.rangecode = e.rangecode
    WHERE 
        nvl(e.catalogueid,P_CATALOGUEID) = P_CATALOGUEID                   
    ORDER BY 
        e.sku;
```

Can someone help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaushik helped me get here, but the solution I have implemented is this:

```
procedure ListCatalogueEntries(P_CUR out sys_refcursor,
                               P_CATALOGUEID varchar2) IS
V_UNIQUE cc_ob_catalogueheader.uniquecatalogue%type;    
BEGIN
    BEGIN            
        SELECT uniquecatalogue 
        INTO V_UNIQUE 
        FROM cc_ob_catalogueheader 
        WHERE CatalogueId = P_CATALOGUEID;    
    END;

    IF V_UNIQUE = 'Y' THEN
        OPEN P_CUR FOR
        SELECT 
            corprd.sku        prodcode,
            corprd.rangecode  cor_rangecode,
            corprd.rangename  cor_rangename,
            corprd.prodcode   cor_colourcode,
            corprd.prodname   cor_colourname,
            corprd.sku        cor_partcode,
            corprd.skudesc    cor_partname,
            corprd.proddesc   cor_partdesc,
            corprd.prodspec   cor_partspec,
            e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
            e.rangename cus_rangename,
            e.productcode cus_colourcode,
            e.productname cus_colourname,
            e.buyercode cus_partcode,
            e.skudescription cus_partname,
            e.skudescription cus_partspec                              
        FROM
            ccvw_web_products corprd
        INNER JOIN 
            cc_ob_catalogueentries e
        ON 
            corprd.sku = e.sku
        WHERE 
            nvl(e.catalogueid,P_CATALOGUEID) = P_CATALOGUEID                   
        ORDER BY 
            e.sku;
    ELSE
        OPEN P_CUR FOR
        SELECT 
            corprd.sku        prodcode,
            corprd.rangecode  cor_rangecode,
            corprd.rangename  cor_rangename,
            corprd.prodcode   cor_colourcode,
            corprd.prodname   cor_colourname,
            corprd.sku        cor_partcode,
            corprd.skudesc    cor_partname,
            corprd.proddesc   cor_partdesc,
            corprd.prodspec   cor_partspec,
            e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
            e.rangename cus_rangename,
            e.productcode cus_colourcode,
            e.productname cus_colourname,
            e.buyercode cus_partcode,
            e.skudescription cus_partname,
            e.skudescription cus_partspec                              
        FROM
            ccvw_web_products corprd
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            cc_ob_catalogueentries e
        ON 
            corprd.rangecode = e.rangecode
        WHERE 
            nvl(e.catalogueid,P_CATALOGUEID) = P_CATALOGUEID                   
        ORDER BY 
            e.sku;
    END IF;          

END ListCatalogueEntries;
```

Which seems to work as I expected

Answer (score 0):

have you try

```
IF P_UNIQUEPRODUCTS = 'Y' THEN
   OPEN P_CUR FOR ...
ELSE 
   OPEN P_CUR FOR ...
END IF;
```

then use `P_CUR`

Comment: Yeah, but I would like it to be like the MSSQL statement (i.e. doing a select into a variable). Can you help me do that?

Comment: Sorry I dont see that in your question. maybe try a simplified version of your problem so we can focus on the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local variable with appropriate size  to store the output from query  with an optional ( though recommended ) handling for `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

```
 PROCEDURE listcatalogueentries (
      p_cur              OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      p_catalogueid      VARCHAR2
 )
      IS

      l_uniqueproducts   VARCHAR2(100);

 BEGIN
 SELECT  uniquecatalogue INTO l_uniqueproducts 
      FROM cc_ob_catalogueheader WHERE Id = p_catalogueid;

      IF
           l_uniqueproducts = 'Y'
      THEN
           OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT corprd.sku prodcode,
                                 corprd.rangecode cor_rangecode,
                                 corprd.rangename cor_rangename,
                                 corprd.prodcode cor_colourcode,
                                 corprd.prodname cor_colourname,
                                 corprd.sku cor_partcode,
                                 corprd.skudesc cor_partname,
                                 corprd.proddesc cor_partdesc,
                                 corprd.prodspec cor_partspec,
                                 e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
                                 e.rangename cus_rangename,
                                 e.productcode cus_colourcode,
                                 e.productname cus_colourname,
                                 e.buyercode cus_partcode,
                                 e.skudescription cus_partname,
                                 e.skudescription cus_partspec
                          FROM ccvw_web_products corprd
                          INNER JOIN cc_ob_catalogueentries e ON corprd.sku = e.sku
                          WHERE nvl(e.catalogueid,p_catalogueid) = p_catalogueid
           ORDER BY e.sku;
      ELSE
           OPEN p_cur FOR SELECT corprd.sku prodcode,
                                 corprd.rangecode cor_rangecode,
                                 corprd.rangename cor_rangename,
                                 corprd.prodcode cor_colourcode,
                                 corprd.prodname cor_colourname,
                                 corprd.sku cor_partcode,
                                 corprd.skudesc cor_partname,
                                 corprd.proddesc cor_partdesc,
                                 corprd.prodspec cor_partspec,
                                 e.rangecode cus_rangecode,
                                 e.rangename cus_rangename,
                                 e.productcode cus_colourcode,
                                 e.productname cus_colourname,
                                 e.buyercode cus_partcode,
                                 e.skudescription cus_partname,
                                 e.skudescription cus_partspec
                          FROM ccvw_web_products corprd
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN cc_ob_catalogueentries e ON corprd.rangecode = e.rangecode
                          WHERE nvl(e.catalogueid,p_catalogueid) = p_catalogueid
           ORDER BY e.sku;
      END IF;

      EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
       THEN 
         show_do_something;
 END listcatalogueentries;
```

Comment: It doesn't compile :(

Comment: Error(655,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Comment: @r3plica : pls check now. Declare statement was  mistake. In procedures directly define variables after IS keyword.

Comment: It needs a begin/end wrapping around the select into statement

Comment: @r3plica : thats not needed. If you provide table ddls and sample data, I can provide you  a working solution. There might be something wrong in your actual code.